# copy-paste in searchbar isn't working while copying from other apps

Tags: ios, copy-paste, uipasteboard

Do I need to explicitly code something to have this feature? After long press on the searchbar, the paste button comes, do I need to implement any delegate method for that button? Or it is implicit?

Comment: It's default built-in functionality for any textfields.

Comment: Paste button is coming but its not pasting the content, which I copied from other apps like safari!

Comment: It should work with any text content. Can you paste the content you want in other app?

Comment: yes, I am able to do so.

Comment: Can you see the text which you manually type in the text field?

Comment: Yes I can see the text I manually type

Comment: Please post your search bar related code for others to get an idea about it along with the delegate and datasource functions implemented if any.

Comment: Simply took a search bar in storyboard , no code related to search bar yet.

Comment: Are you pasting multiple lines? In that case sometimes you don't readily see the pasted text but its pasted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165415/discussion-between-yogi-and-user804417).

Comment: I m pasting only a single word.

Comment: How is that searchbar created and how is it added? what is the view hierarchy there ? without these it's very hard to guess.

Comment: The issue isn’t only with the search bar, no text field is working while trying to paste! IOS11 is working fine out of box, issue is only with iOS10.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paste a string then you can use below code which is help to retrieve a copied data from paste board and set a string to your textfield by click on button..

```
    @IBAction func StringGet(_ sender:UIButton){
                   for key in UIPasteboardTypeListString
                    {
                        print(key as! String)
                        let data = UIPasteboard.general.data(forPasteboardType: key as! String, inItemSet: nil)
                        if data != nil
                        {
                            let str = UIPasteboard.general.string!
                            self.yourString == str
                           } }
             }
```

Comment: On which button click event it will be written? At long press the default paste button pops up & I want to paste the content in that button click event. Or you want me to add a new button & stringet will be the action of that button ?

Comment: Yes, you can add your manual button because pasteboard may not allow to paste copied content from another app so you have to retrieve in this way and set a text to textfield.

Comment: My requirement is it should work as default functionality. Adding a new button will work but that’s not the requirement! Copy pasting from another app works, try with apple apps like notes , safari etc.